# Beacon contract contructor seems to call address 0x02?

Tags: constructor, opcode

The Beacon (Eth 2.0 deposit) contract was once deployed using a certain (constructor) script, like every other contract on the EVM blockchain. While analyzing that constructor script, it seems that it would call the nonexisting address 0x02 during contract creation. What am I overlooking?

I copied the beginning of the Beacon construction script below, ending at the opcode STATICCALL. While running that with an (admittedly buggy) evm-opcode simulator, when reaching the STATICCALL statement it would have 0x02 on the stack as the parameter that would be used as the address.

In all the opcodes of this snippet, there's also no PUSHed parameter that looks like an address (I'd expect a PUSH20). The only other way I see that an address might be loaded is through SLOAD at line 0x2e, which by the way is also a strange statement since there's no SSTORE statement before it. In my understanding, right before the constructor of a contract is called, the storage is always empty.

I got this opcode script by fetching the first transaction (i.e. the construction) of the Beacon contract at address `0x00000000219ab540356cBB839Cbe05303d7705Fa` through the etherscan api.

```
  0x0         60    PUSH1             0x80                                                                    
  0x2         60    PUSH1             0x40                                                                    
  0x4         52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0x5         34    CALLVALUE                                                                                 
  0x6         80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0x7         15    ISZERO                                                                                    
  0x8         61    PUSH2             0x10                                                                    
  0xb         57    JUMPI                                                                                     
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0xc         60    PUSH1             0x00                                                                    
  0xe         80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0xf         fd    REVERT                                                                                    
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0x10        5b    JUMPDEST                                                                                  
  0x11        50    POP                                                                                       
  0x12        60    PUSH1             0x00                                                                    
  0x14        5b    JUMPDEST                                                                                  
  0x15        60    PUSH1             0x1f                                                                    
  0x17        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x18        10    LT                                                                                        
  0x19        15    ISZERO                                                                                    
  0x1a        61    PUSH2             0x0102                                                                  
  0x1d        57    JUMPI                                                                                     
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0x1e        60    PUSH1             0x02                                                                    
  0x20        60    PUSH1             0x21                                                                    
  0x22        82    DUP3                                                                                      
  0x23        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x25        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x26        10    LT                                                                                        
  0x27        61    PUSH2             0x2c                                                                    
  0x2a        57    JUMPI                                                                                     
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0x2b        fe    INVALID                                                                                   
  0x2c        5b    JUMPDEST                                                                                  
  0x2d        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x2e        54    SLOAD                                                                                     
  0x2f        60    PUSH1             0x21                                                                    
  0x31        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0x32        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x34        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x35        10    LT                                                                                        
  0x36        61    PUSH2             0x3b                                                                    
  0x39        57    JUMPI                                                                                     
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0x3a        fe    INVALID                                                                                   
  0x3b        5b    JUMPDEST                                                                                  
  0x3c        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x3d        54    SLOAD                                                                                     
  0x3e        60    PUSH1             0x40                                                                    
  0x40        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x41        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x43        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x44        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0x45        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0x46        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x47        52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0x48        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x4a        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x4b        82    DUP3                                                                                      
  0x4c        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x4d        52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0x4e        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x50        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x51        92    SWAP3                                                                                     
  0x52        50    POP                                                                                       
  0x53        50    POP                                                                                       
  0x54        50    POP                                                                                       
  0x55        60    PUSH1             0x40                                                                    
  0x57        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x58        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x5a        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x5b        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0x5c        3     SUB                                                                                       
  0x5d        3     SUB                                                                                       
  0x5e        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x5f        52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0x60        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0x61        60    PUSH1             0x40                                                                    
  0x63        52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0x64        60    PUSH1             0x40                                                                    
  0x66        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x67        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0x68        82    DUP3                                                                                      
  0x69        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0x6a        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x6b        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0x6c        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x6e        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x6f        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0x70        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0x71        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0x72        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0x73        5b    JUMPDEST                                                                                  
  0x74        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x76        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0x77        10    LT                                                                                        
  0x78        61    PUSH2             0x92                                                                    
  0x7b        57    JUMPI                                                                                     
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0x7c        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0x7d        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x7e        82    DUP3                                                                                      
  0x7f        52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0x80        60    PUSH1             0x1f                                                                    
  0x82        19    NOT                                                                                       
  0x83        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0x84        92    SWAP3                                                                                     
  0x85        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x86        91    SWAP2                                                                                     
  0x87        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x89        91    SWAP2                                                                                     
  0x8a        82    DUP3                                                                                      
  0x8b        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x8c        91    SWAP2                                                                                     
  0x8d        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0x8e        61    PUSH2             0x73                                                                    
  0x91        56    JUMP                                                                                      
  ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  0x92        5b    JUMPDEST                                                                                  
  0x93        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x94        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0x95        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0x96        60    PUSH1             0x20                                                                    
  0x98        93    SWAP4                                                                                     
  0x99        84    DUP5                                                                                      
  0x9a        3     SUB                                                                                       
  0x9b        61    PUSH2             0x0100                                                                  
  0x9e        a     EXP                                                                                       
  0x9f        60    PUSH1             0x00                                                                    
  0xa1        19    NOT                                                                                       
  0xa2        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0xa3        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0xa4        19    NOT                                                                                       
  0xa5        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0xa6        92    SWAP3                                                                                     
  0xa7        16    AND                                                                                       
  0xa8        91    SWAP2                                                                                     
  0xa9        16    AND                                                                                       
  0xaa        17    OR                                                                                        
  0xab        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0xac        52    MSTORE                                                                                    
  0xad        60    PUSH1             0x40                                                                    
  0xaf        51    MLOAD                                                                                     
  0xb0        91    SWAP2                                                                                     
  0xb1        90    SWAP1                                                                                     
  0xb2        93    SWAP4                                                                                     
  0xb3        1     ADD                                                                                       
  0xb4        94    SWAP5                                                                                     
  0xb5        50    POP                                                                                       
  0xb6        91    SWAP2                                                                                     
  0xb7        92    SWAP3                                                                                     
  0xb8        50    POP                                                                                       
  0xb9        50    POP                                                                                       
  0xba        80    DUP1                                                                                      
  0xbb        83    DUP4                                                                                      
  0xbc        3     SUB                                                                                       
  0xbd        81    DUP2                                                                                      
  0xbe        85    DUP6                                                                                      
  0xbf        5a    GAS                                                                                       
  0xc0        fa    STATICCALL
  ....
  ....
```

This snippet as hex bytes: (stack-exchange does not allow me to post the whole lengthy script)

```
608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060005b601f8110156101025760026021826020811061002c57fe5b01546021836020811061003b57fe5b015460405160200180838152602001828152602001925050506040516020818303038152906040526040518082805190602001908083835b602083106100925780518252601f199092019160209182019101610073565b51815160209384036101000a60001901801990921691161790526040519190930194509192505080830381855afa
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

address(2) hosts a precompiled contract ( a "smart contract" that is actually blent in the VM) that computes the sha256 hash of a number sent to it as argument. Actually, address 1 to 9 are all precompiles. Read [this](https://www.rareskills.io/post/solidity-precompiles) if you want for more info

Comment: Indeed, the original source code at https://etherscan.io/address/0x00000000219ab540356cbb839cbe05303d7705fa#code mentions sha256() calls in its constructor.